# Linq query join one table row to another table multiple row

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

**Table name: Namelist**

---

```
id | Name
------------
1  |xxxxx
2  |yyyyy
```

**Table name: Category**

---

```
id | Nameid |Categoryid
-----------------
1  |1       |5
2  |1       |4
3  |2       |3
4  |2       |8
```

I need a linq query result like this

---

```
id | Name   |Categoryid
-----------------
1  |xxxx       |5,4
2  |yyyy       |3,8
```

**I tried below linq but it displays first category id only**

```
var list = from n in namelist 
           join c in category on n.id equals c.nameid 
           select new 
           { 
              n.id,
              n.name,
              c.categoryid
           }
```

Comment: Linq-To-Objects or do you use a database? If so, which LINQ provider(f.e. Linq-To-Sql).

Comment: Yes i using database

Comment: Join the tables on Namelist.id and Category.Nameid then group by Nameid and use linq to concat the categories ids distinct in a string

Comment: Do you actually want `categoryId` as a comma separated string property? Or do you want it grouped?

Comment: yes @Jamiec i need as a comma separated string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [Group Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531303.aspx) and join all the category id's in the group with `String.Join` like this:-

```
 var result = (from n in namelist
              join c in categories 
              on n.Id equals c.NameId into g
              select new 
                       {
                          id = n.Id,
                          Name = n.Name,
                          CategorieIds = g.Select(x => x.CategoryId)
                       }).AsEnumerable()
                         .Select(x => new 
                                   { 
                                     Id = x.id, 
                                     Name = x.Name, 
                                     CategoryIds = String.Join(",",x.CategorieIds)) 
                                   });
```

Comment: 'string.Join` can't be converted into sql

Comment: your linq display error like "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: @r.vengadesh - Updated code according to Entity framework. You need to bring the selected object back in memory using `AsEnumerable` and then apply `string.join`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the query now reads the whole table namelist and categories into memory.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - No it loads only joined `id,name` and `categoryids` in memory not the whole table. That is the reason I have `select new  { Id..` .

Answer (score 4):

You can try `String.Join`:

```
var list = namelist
    .Select(n => new { 
        n.id,
        n.name,
        categoryids = String.Join(",", category
            .Where(c => c.nameid == n.id)
            .Select(c => c.categoryid))
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx). I modified your statement:

```
var list = from n in namelist 
           join c in category on n.id equals c.nameid 
           group g by new { n.id, n.name }
           select new 
           { 
              id = g.Key.id,
              Name = g.Key.name,
              Categoryid = String.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.c.categoryid))
           }
```

Comment: second parameter of `String.Join` does not expect a single string value. your code will not even compile

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid oops, my bad

Comment: Your code was right before you updated it with the `.First().c...` bit

Answer (score -2):

First you take a join on `NameList` and `Category` table and then bring them into objects using `ToList` or `AsEnumerable` methods like

```
var list = (from n in db.NameList 
           join c in db.Category on n.id equals c.nameid 
           select new 
           { 
              id = n.id,
              Name = n.name,
              Categoryid = c.id
           }).ToList();
var list2 = from l in list
group by new {l.id, l.Name} into groupings
from g in groupings select new{
   g.Key.id,
   g.Key.Name,
   CategoryId = string.Joing(",", groupings.Where(x=>x.NameId == g.Key.id).Select(y=>y.CategoryId))
};
```

The benefit of using `ToList` for fetching data from db is that you will only one query in database and all required records are fetched in the memory. The second statement will group those records by `id` and `Name` and will apply `string.Join` on `CategoryId`. Please note that if you use `string.join` method on `Linq-to-Entities` query, it will fail because this method cannot be converted into sql expression.

Comment: would appreciate reason for down voting?

Comment: I didn't downvote but there's absolutely no benefit in fetching data from the database before joining.

Comment: they are not fetched before joining, rather before grouping

Comment: Yeah, I meant grouping... But maybe people alos downvote because this question doesn't really need a 4th answer and your answer is way too elaborate. A few lines as in Tim Schmelter's answer suffice.

Comment: Tim's answer results in n+1 queries. wouldn't it?